# Get block of text in a txt file with regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm just starting with python regular expressions. I read many topics but can't adapt solutions to my problem.

I've got a file like this one :

```
**** FILE.NAME ***
Fisrt sentence
    blablabla
    blablabla
    blablabla
    blablabla

Second sentence
    blablabla
    blablabla
    blablabla
    blablabla
```

I'm looking for a regex expression to extract several text blocks of my file :

```
Fisrt sentence
    blablabla
    blablabla
    blablabla
    blablabla
```

Then :

```
Second sentence
    blablabla
    blablabla
    blablabla
    blablabla
```

with a separation of sentences and blabla blocks. I tried something like this but not working :

```
^(\w+[^\n]*?)(.*)\n{2}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
re.findall(r'^(\w.*)\n([\s\S]*?)(?:\n{2,}|\Z)', text, re.M)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tuyEQV/1).

The pattern matches:

- `^` - start of a line (due to `re.M`, the `^` matches line start positions)
- `(\w.*)` - Group 1: aword char followed with any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `\n` - a newline
- `([\s\S]*?)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `(?:\n{2,}|\Z)` - either two or more newlines (`\n{2,}`) or (`|`) end of string (`\Z`).

Answer (score 3):

General rule of thumb: Don't use `re` when `str` methods suffice.

In this case you can call the [`.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method on multiple newlines:

```
s.split('\n\n')
```

returns

```
['Fisrt sentence\n    blablabla\n    blablabla\n    blablabla\n    blablabla',
 'Second sentence\n    blablabla\n    blablabla\n    blablabla\n    blablabla']
```